# Guest machine cannot connect to internet in VMWare Workstation

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, vmware-workstation

I have two virtual machines and one is acting as a domain controller.
I have both configured to use NAT network adapter and I has set static IP addresses for both servers, like this:

```
Domain controller
------------------
IP: 192.168.238.100
subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.238.2 (because I am using NAT)
Preferred DNS server 192.168.238.100
```

IP address of VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 is: 192.168.238.1 so I added this IP address as default gateway: 192.168.238.2

I configured the other server the same way just changing the last number for the IP address and I used ...238.100 as the preferred DNS. I was able to access internet before. Today, I started my vm and I could not connect to internet at all. I can ping both machines by name, e.g: ping dc01 and they respond correctly. I have been trying to solve this since this morning.

I removed the network adapter from the VM and I added it again, but did not work. Tried to remove the defaultgateway in registry but that did not work either.

what am I doing wrong or what I should check?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my computer right now to check out the default IPs used by VMware for gateways and such, but are you sure that 192.168.238.2 address is the gateway?  For some reason I thought it was usually like .254 or something.

I recommend two things.

1. On the VM that is not a DC temporarily configure the network to use DHCP instead of static IPs and then run `ipconfig /all` from a command line to see what the gateway normally is when VMware assigns it.
2. If the non domain controller is a member of the domain it will need to have the DC setup as it's DNS server.  So, you should probably setup your DC's DNS server to forward queries to the VMware NAT DNS server IP (`192.168.238.100`).  That way all the domain member DNS queries pass through the DC as they should for domain operations, but you can still query for www.superuser.con also.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the post above. I have posted the ipconfig above in my post. I removed the static IP address and set it to get it automatically.

When I went home and powered the machine, I was able to access internet. I use wireless at home, but here at work I am connecting via a cable. So, what could be the difference? I am not that well acquainted with Networking, but I will try to figure out what you meant with the second point.

Comment: I doubt any of my answer will help if it works at home but not at work.  Those solutions only make sense if the problem is consistent.  Did it work when the IP settings were changed to DHCP/automatic settings?